# Creating conditional axis labels in R?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, plot

I'm wondering why, when running the below R function, I get the following warning:

`Warning message:
In if (is.na(labels)) axTicks(2) else labels :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Since everything works fine except this warning message, I was wondering how I could eliminate this warning message?

```
bb <- function(labels = NA){

 plot(1, yaxt = "n")

 lab <- if(is.na(labels)) axTicks(2) else labels ## Why this gives a warning message?

 axis(2, at = axTicks(2), labels = lab)
}
# Example of use:
bb(labels = paste0("Hi ", 1:5))
```

Comment: `is.na(labels)` will return a _vector_ of TRUE/FALSE values, only the first of which will be evaluated in the `if` statement. Are you trying to replace ANY NA values in `labels`?

Comment: @jdobres, yes exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `labels` is a vector, `is.na(labels)` will return a vector of TRUE/FALSE values. In R, the standard `if` statement must evaluate to a *single* TRUE/FALSE value. The warning message is telling you that `if` produced multiple values and is evaluating truth based on the first one.

If your goal is to check to see if *any* values in `labels` are `NA`, do:

```
if (any(is.na(labels))) {
  ...
}
```

If your goal is to replace the `NA` elements of some vector with the values of another vector, you probably want `ifelse()`.